# How to change width in matplotlib barh plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'll have only one record in my 1st List and count of that record in my 2nd List. I need to put them in a horizontal bar graph.
Value of List 1 in Y axis and value of List 2 as a label of the bar.
The below code is giving me the bar whose width I can't change. How I can change the width? It's looking awkward with this large width.
If not in matplotlib, can i use some other python library to achieve this?

```
import os
import cx_Oracle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r_c = [Sales_report_2020]
a_i =  [1311]

 
# Figure Size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(12, 8))
#replace the None with integer 0
b = [0 if x is None else x for x in a_i]
print(b)
 
# Horizontal Bar Plot
plt.barh(r_c,b,height=0.5)
plt.ylim(-0.5, len(b) - 0.5)
ax.tick_params(width=0.5,length=6)
 

 
# Add annotation to bars
for i in ax.patches:
    plt.text(i.get_width()+0.2, i.get_y()+0.27,
            "{:1.0f}".format(i.get_width()),
             fontsize = 10, fontweight ='bold',
             color ='grey') #str(round((i.get_width()), 2))
 
# Add Plot Title
ax.set_title('DTP!',
             loc ='center', )
 
# Add Text watermark
fig.text(0.9, 0.15, 'STPREPORT', fontsize = 12,
         color ='grey', ha ='right', va ='bottom',
         alpha = 0.7)
 
 
path = r"\\ssd.COM\View\Folder_Redirect\id\Documents\Conda_Envs"
 
os.chdir(path)
plt.savefig(path + '\BAR.png')
 
# Show Plot
plt.show()
conn.close()
```

[image]

Comment: does reduction of `height` parameter in `plt.barh(r_c,b,height=0.5)` help?

Comment: @YevKad, no :| Tried to change it's size as well like 1/1.5. It remains same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` and `height` parameters in `barh` can help you a little bit, but since there is only one record, `matplotlib` is probably adjusting the plot automatically to make it look bigger than you need. Adjusting your `ylim` should help you. I can't execute your code because I don't have the data, but the following illustrates what I mean:

For example,

```
plt.barh(1311, width=0.01, height=0.01)
```

gives you

[image: example one]

while

```
plt.barh(1311, width=20, height=20)
```

gives you

[image: example two]

But, if you set a better `ylim`, you can get a better-looking horizontal bar.

```
plt.barh(1311, width=0.5, height=20)
plt.ylim([1200, 1400])
```

[image: example 3]

Of course, you would edit these values to get your desired result.

Comment: Thanks! Have tried to plot this way but the data is not showing anything.

Comment: plt.barh(R_ID_01,1311, width=0.5, height=20); plt.ylimit([1200,1400]). This value 1311 is a dynamic one and it could be anything: 0-10000, so, how the ylimit would be dynamically set based on this value?

Comment: Well, you could do `plt.ylim([x - 1000, x + 1000])`, where `x` is your dynamic value. That will center your value on the y axis and behave similarly to what I showed on this answer. You can further change the `1000` to make your bar look wider or thinner.

Comment: Thanks Camilo. But inside plt.barh() I need to pass three parameters actually. plt.barh(repot_name,count_of_the_report,height). Will it work? Because i'm getting blank plot.

Comment: What is `repot_name`? plt.barh() expects y, width, height in that order. So if your `count_of_the_report` is your "dynamic value", then that should be the first parameter.

Comment: Report name is my 1st list which would contain only one report name- Sales_Report_2020 and this would be placed in y axis. count_of_the_report is my second list, would contain the count of the report for a specific period as per the query parameter. 1311 here is the count value and that value needs to be displayed as a label of the bar.

Comment: I've updated the question for better clarity, please let me know if I need to add anything.

Comment: Can you provide at least one value for `r_c`? It's hard to pinpoint what your problem is, if I can't exactly reproduce your problematic plot.

Comment: Sales_Report_2020, this String will be the value for r_c and it needs to placed in Y axis. Value of this report (1311) should be placed in X axis as well as label of the bar should display this 1311 value.

Comment: Try `plt.ylim([len(b) - 10, len(b) + 10])`. I tested your code changing only that line and it works fine, i.e, I'm getting a thin horizontal bar. If you decrease 10, you make it wider.

Comment: Thanks....somehow it's manageable as per your suggestion. :) Do you have any idea how many data we can plot in a horizontal bar graph so that they don't overlap each other? I've tried upto 60 data, after that it's overlapping.

Comment: Glad it helps. Regarding the amount of data, even if they start to overlap, remember that you can increase `figsize` and `dpi`, and I assure you that you will be able to fit more data in your plot.

Comment: Thank You! If possible, please have a look at this problem- https://stackoverflow.com/q/67215430/15693567